# Emulate Key Presses On an App that takes no Win Messages

Tags: c#, keyboard, mouse, pinvoke

I want to send an Application Key Presses, To Automate some stuff that has to be done repeatedly and So I don't always have to cramp my fingers.

In C#, it's nice to use SendKeys.Send(), but this won't work because the Application doesn't take Windows Messages. SendKeys.SendWait() does nothing at all.

How would I STILL Simulate the Keyboard events?

Come To Think of It, I was going to use some P/Invoke to simulate Mouse Events too, but If it takes no messages, How Can I get around that?

---

**EDIT** - I can use mouse and keyboard to interact with the program, I just cannot manipulate it with Windows Messages sent from my own Code.

Comment: Is this a console application ?

Comment: No, It is a Windowed Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml)?

Comment: AutoIt - Perfect. I was able to Import the AutoItX Library into my Project in VS and It worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a console app? If so, maybe you should be `SendKeys`'ing to the command shell instance it is running in.

Comment: No, This Program has no Console, sadly.

Comment: It doesn't have windows, and it doesn't have a console for normal text entry. How do you normally interact with it that you would be typing to it then?

Comment: It has a Window. It just won't take Windows Messages.

Comment: How do you type into it normally? Thought control?

Comment: I use my keyboard. I'm sorry if the question was phrased in a bad way, I'll do my best to amend it so it shows clearly that I CAN manipulate it, just no from my Code.

Comment: If you can type into it, then you can use windows messages - this is how the keyboard messages are sent to the program

Comment: When I try to use Sendkeys.Send, I get an InvalidOperationException which tells me the Application accepts no Windows Messages. This is Windows 7, which is similar to Vista in User priveleges. I would assume the App takes no messages from Processes with low rights, but still from those with system rights, like the keyboard driver.